# C# Using keywords with streams

Tags: c#, stream

Should I be using the `using` keyword or a dispose method with the following code (since I am opening a stream):

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = Deserialize<Dog>(new FileStream(@"C:\Documents and Settings\name\Desktop\demo.xml", FileMode.Open));
         }

        static T Deserialize<T>(Stream s)
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(s);
        }
    }
```

If not, can you please explain why not (does a new FileStream automatically dispose/close the stream)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `using`:

```
using(var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\path\demo.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var x = Deserialize<Dog>(stream);
    // more code ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you should dispose the stream. If you were to use the [File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) for example, this static method would open a stream and dispose it for you. I would suggest a **Using**, this is because it'll handle exceptions too. For example in this noddy example:

This version correctly disposes the FileStream:

```
using(FileStream fs = FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
   throw new Exception();
}
```

This example leaks the resources used by the FileStream, you could add try/catch blocks but then it's less readable.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
throw new Exception();
fs.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `using block` , he execute in the end of treatment `Dispose method`.

You use using, because `FileStream is non managed object`, so `Garbage collector don't have informatiosn abouts this object` in order to clean, so the developper must clean ressource in order to help your GC.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

you should use **Using** with everything that implements IDisposable :)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you should use using. But why? Well, as already mentioned you should use using for all objects that implements IDisposable.

In your case, FileStream inherits from the Stream object which is implementing IDisposable. Read more about FileStream here: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)